# AC:R Multiplayer: how do some high level players re-use abilities so fast

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In AC:B you unlocked [improvements to your powers by unlocking challenges](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Multiplayer_Abilities). In AC:R you can craft abilities once you're level 30 instead.

However some high level players (prestiged at least once I think) seem to be able to use smoke bombs insanely fast - I've been smoked twice in less than 30 seconds by the same player several times. This is significantly quicker than I can craft.

Do you get additional crafting options once you prestige?

Am I missing some combination of perks that gives you the ability again in less than 30 seconds?

Comment: Time goes by pretty fast if you craft your abilities to have two improved cooldowns paired with the **Overall Cooldowns** perk.  **Smoke Bombs** cooldowns are already pretty short already.  All my sets have **Overall Cooldowns** with **Smoke Bombs** crafted with two cooldown reductions because they are just _that_ handy to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall Cooldowns (lvl 40) takes 10 seconds off all your cooldown timers, so one could drop a smoke bomb every 50 seconds if they pick that perk. If someone spends time crafting their abilities (at 80 Abstergo Credits a pop) they could reduce the default cooldown on Smoke Bomb to 45 seconds, so if you add in the perk one could conceivably get their cooldown on smoke bombs down to 35 seconds.

Comment: Rapid Reload Smoke Bomb? How do you get that? There was one in Brotherhood for completing the smoke bomb challenge, but I have't seen anything like that yet in Revelations and I'm level 45.

Comment: I may be getting my games crossed - In AC:B you could complete the challenge "Cut Through The Fog" by using Smoke Bomb to block and stun pursuers. I'm digging around to make sure that Revelations has the same challenge. I have found a bit more info relating to the crafting in mp, though. By burning 80 Creds you can customize abilities. If you tweak Smoke Bomb's cooldown twice you can get the default to 45 seconds. Add that to the other two perks would get the cooldown to 25 seconds, so it's probably that you were popped by someone who has been spending time tweaking their loadout.

Comment: ok - final edit to the answer until I can get home and check my strategy guide. I can't find anywhere that says that the Rapid Reload ablility is available in AC:R, so I'm removing that from the text. The minimum cooldown time for smoke bombs, after crafting and Overall Cooldowns should be 35 seconds.

Comment: I dug into the official strategy guide from Piggyback last night and checked over the multiplayer section. There's no mention of the Rapid Reload for the smoke bombs, so I was definitely getting my wires crossed with Brotherhood. As it stands, my answer above is the best info I can provide - at lvl 30 you can craft the cooldown on smoke bombs down to 45 seconds and when you hit lvl 40 you can add the Overall Cooldowns to your loadout to knock it down to 35. When you were playing was it blatantly obvious that the smoke bombs were less than 30 seconds apart?

Comment: I was going off my own cooldown timers, so I could certainly be 5 seconds out.